# MVC4 Json Null object handling

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, null, string

MVC Framework 4.0, some actions return HTML, and some are required to return Json.  The below model is an example of the C# Object I'm returning using `Json(myObject);`

```
public class resultModel 
{    
    public string status;
    public string message;

    public subResultModel myChild;
}

public class subResultModel
{
    public string status;
    public string message;
}
```

The `Json()` method interprets a fully instantiated object just fine, however, if `myChild` is `null`, the Json value for the key is `null`.  To meet a wider variety of web standards, I'd like to have the result be `""`.  I'm not sure how to go about this, I use `Json()` in a wide number of places in my code, and to avoid the overhead I'd prefer to not have to switch to Json.NET.

i.e. from

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "message":"",
   "myChild":null
}
```

to

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "message":"",
   "myChild":""
}
```